# Show $\int_{\mathbb R} f * g \ d \lambda = \int_{\mathbb R} f \ d \lambda \cdot \int_{\mathbb R} g \ d \lambda$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

> Suppose $f,g \in \mathcal L_{\mathbb C}^1(\lambda)$. Show $\int_{\mathbb R} f * g \ d \lambda = \int_{\mathbb R} f \ d \lambda \cdot \int_{\mathbb R} g \ d \lambda$.

I see that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f * g| \ d \lambda = \int_{\mathbb R} |f| \ d \lambda \cdot  \int_{\mathbb R} |g| \ d \lambda$, however I don't see how to use this result or if it should be used. Trying to compute the integrals in question directly hasn't given me much insight. Could someone help me out ?

I should be said that $f * g$ denotes the folding of $f$ and $g$ and $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

$f * g(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x-y)g(y) \ \lambda(dy)$ where defined.

Edit: using Tonelli I get $\int_{\mathbb R} f * g \ d \lambda = \int_{\mathbb R} g(y) \int_{\mathbb R} f(x-y) \ \lambda(dx) \lambda(dy)$

Comment: What does $*$ represent? Convolution?

Comment: It is now explained :-)

Comment: Folding isn't a standard term. It indeed is convolution (which is the much more common term).

Comment: Do you know Fubini-Tonelli? This is an application of that.

Comment: Now, I've written clearly what the folding is.

Comment: Please see where I get stuck using Tonelli @CameronWilliams

Comment: @user111854 Now all you need is to evaluate the iterated integral. There is a property of the Lebesgue measure that makes evaluating the inner integral easy.

Comment: That it is translation invariant ?

Comment: @CameronWilliams In German, the convolution is called Faltung, the verb is falten. The non-mathematical meaning of "falten" is "to fold".

Comment: @user111854 Exactly. So, using that, you get the result directly.